# Should I use ViewModel with UseCase?

Tags: android, architecture, clean-architecture

This is more of a question about designing applications, rather than fixing a specific issue.

So most Android tutorials I see use `ViewModel` as a layer between the data source and the views. Hence my first impression was that a `ViewModel` is supposed to handle data fetching and updating, but then I read about 'Use cases' which most Android samples don't even mention and I don't understand how all these parts fit together. What's the relationship between a `ViewModel` and a use case?

Answer (score 1):

1) Clean Architecture this is approach how to design your application. This is not about specific realization like in case of `ViewModel`.

2) If you looked at the official Android documentation you will not find any mentions of Clean Architecture. Google not forcing this approach.

3) `ViewModel` this is part of MVVM design pattern. So if we looking info Clean Architecture MMVM can be part of Presentation layer (same as MVP commonly used in this layer). But you still need UseCase to make interactions between Data layer and Presentation layer.

Comment: Basically Viewmodel and Usecase both represent the business logic MVVM not included in the Presentation layer if you read the MVVM documentation because ViewModel totally handles the business logic that's why we separate the MVVM from MVP.

Comment: In MVP we Usecase for handling the business logic but in MVVM we have the ViewModel for this purpose.